# Klaxon: Expected a name but got LEFT_BRACE

Tags: json, kotlin, klaxon

How can I read a "complex" json using Klaxon?
I'm trying to use klaxon's stream api [as documentation say](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon#streamingApi) .

I'm using the beginObject method. If I use a json as given in the example everything is fine

```
val objectString = """{
 "name" : "Joe",
 "age" : 23,
 "flag" : true,
 "array" : [1, 3],
 "obj1" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
}"""
```

But if I try to parse a json with a nested object as the following example I get the following error: "Expected a name but got LEFT_BRACE"

```
val objectString = """{
 "name" : "Joe",
 "age" : 23,
 "flag" : true,
 "array" : [1, 3],
 "obj1" : { 
             "hello": { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } 
          }
}"""
```

I don't see any reported issues in the github repo, so I wonder if there is a way to get this working.

cheers

Comment: Would you mind providing the code where you try to parse the JSON?

Comment: sure, [it is here](https://gist.github.com/isijara/a4c95ff3e1bc410571fb8861b63158f5)

Comment: Also, here is a repo for convenience https://github.com/isijara/klaxon-failing-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I checked out the source, and it seems that `nextObject()` assumes that you are dealing with a simple key value object, where values are not objects.

Anyway, there is another way to parse a JSON of the format you specified, like below:

```
val objectString = """{
         "name" : "Joe",
         "age" : 23,
         "flag" : true,
         "array" : [1, 2, 3],
         "obj1" : { "hello": {"a" : 1, "b" : 2 } }
    }"""

class ABObj(val a: Int, val b: Int)

class HelloObj(val hello: ABObj)

class Obj(val name: String, val age: Int, val flag: Boolean, val array: List<Any>, val obj1: HelloObj)


val r = Klaxon().parse<Obj>(objectString)

// r is your parsed object
print(r!!.name) // prints Joe
print(r!!.array) // prints [1, 2, 3]
```

The classes I created are like below:

`ABObj` represents this JSON:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

`HelloObj` represents this JSON:

```
{"hello": {"a": 1, "b": 2}}
```

And finally, `Obj` refers to the top level object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to only use the streaming api, but it seems it will have to be this way, thanks @TGO

Answer (score 1):

With the Streaming API, you are in charge of parsing objects and arrays yourself, so when you encounter the name "obj1", you need to start a new `beginObject() { ... }` and parse that object there.

The documentation that you linked does exactly that:

`while (reader.hasNext()) {
            val readName = reader.nextName()
            when (readName) {
                "name" -> name = reader.nextString()
                "age" -> age = reader.nextInt()
                "flag" -> flag = reader.nextBoolean()
                "array" -> array = reader.nextArray()
                "obj1" -> obj1 = reader.nextObject()`

Comment: That would be a nested `beginObject()`? If it is, do I have to start a new JsonReader? I am facing the same problem, can you please show how to do it, based onthe example in the original question?